# Tomcat application 404 could not load - application at context path could not be started

Tags: java, tomcat, odk

I am trying to deploy a prepackaged WAR file (ODK Aggregate), using:

- Centos
- JVM 1.8.0_191-b12
- Tomcat 7

My other webapps will load (sample, manager, some test apps), but this specific one will not - I get a 404, which makes sense because it fails to load when I start tomcat (or when I try to start it through the manager). The catalina log indicates 'SEVERE: Context [/jamiibora] startup failed due to previous errors' and 'SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file'. The localhost log file is empty.

I have tried adding a logging.properties file as per [Tomcat: One or more listeners failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639816/tomcat-one-or-more-listeners-failed-to-start). However, I don't get any additional output in catalina or localhost log files (note that I do not have a CATALINA_HOME env variable).

Suggestions welcome.

cat /var/log/tomcat/catalina.2019-02-03.log

```
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 1 2018 16:39:09 UTC
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.76.0
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_191-b12
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/share/tomcat
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/share/tomcat
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/cache/tomcat/temp
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.17 using APR version 1.4.8.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017)
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 580 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/JarScanner/JarScanFilter'.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war has finished in 640 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/jamiibora.war
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:50 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'Context/JarScanner/JarScanFilter'.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/jamiibora] startup failed due to previous errors
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/jamiibora] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/jamiibora] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/jamiibora.war has finished in 4,853 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/examples
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 333 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/sample
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/sample has finished in 175 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 219 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/manager
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 409 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/test
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/test has finished in 151 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6859 ms
Feb 03, 2019 5:34:00 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase findResourceInternal
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load .  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
```

cat /var/log/tomcat/localhost.2019-02-03.log

```
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Feb 03, 2019 5:33:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@5d04f344')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opendatakit.org/aggregate-tomcat), ODK Aggregate requires Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the environment variables, make sure JDK, JRE, Catalina_home, Catalina_base and Mysql path are set in the environmental variables

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).