# Tomcat: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ubuntu-18.04, axelor

I am new to tomcat or programming in general. I have tomcat 8.5 installed on ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I am trying to deploy a WAR file. From the web manager, I got this error message upon trying to start the application:

*FAIL - Application at context path [/axelor] could not be started*

I used tail to follow catalina.out on the terminal and I can see that during the process, it outputs the following lines:

```
05-May-2020 15:52:30.127 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
05-May-2020 15:52:30.129 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/axelor] startup failed due to previous errors
05-May-2020 15:52:30.233 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
```

After looking it up, I have created a logging file in WEB-INF/classes

Since I am not experienced, I do not know what to look for anymore with that many lines.

After following the guide suggested, I have these lines:

```
05-May-2020 15:52:30.124 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
    com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/xml/ws/Service;
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4960)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:51)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:581)
        at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:49)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:122)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.getInjector(AppContextListener.java:108)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceServletContextListener.contextInitialized(GuiceServletContextListener.java:45)
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.contextInitialized(AppContextListener.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1383)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:694)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/xml/ws/Service;
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2049)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3976)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4960)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:51)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.get(MembersInjectorStore.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:74)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
        ... 56 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/xml/ws/Service;
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getDeclaredFields(InjectionPoint.java:760)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:670)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:378)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:661)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:617)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:603)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:932)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:852)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:291)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:222)
        at com.google.inject.internal.SingleFieldInjector.<init>(SingleFieldInjector.java:39)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.getInjectors(MembersInjectorStore.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.createWithListeners(MembersInjectorStore.java:93)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore.access$000(MembersInjectorStore.java:36)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorStore$1.create(MembersInjectorStore.java:41)
        at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045)
        ... 71 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.Service
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
        ... 96 more
05-May-2020 15:52:30.127 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
05-May-2020 15:52:30.129 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/axelor] startup failed due to previous errors
05-May-2020 15:52:30.233 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.axelor.web.AppContextListener]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.axelor.web.AppContextListener.contextDestroyed(AppContextListener.java:101)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4748)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5405)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1383)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:694)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:218)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:668)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
05-May-2020 15:52:30.237 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [axelor] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Can someone help me find my problem?

Comment: tail by default only displays last 10 lines. I feel like there might be more information in the logs that might help troubleshooting.

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640479/2700022 & restart tomcat, you will have more entries in the logs, then update the new logs in the question,

Comment: sometimes localhost* log files help.  In general it'll either be in catalina.out or "some other designated log file of you app"

Comment: @user2700022 I have updated the logs in my question after following the guide. It is overwhelming to say the least!

Comment: @rogerdpack I have looked for other log files in the app but unfortunately there does not seem to be any does tomcat have other logs?

Comment: @marekb Seems the war was not built properly, many class not found error, if you are not the developer, you should inform whoever provided you with the war file.

Comment: @user2700022 Thank you I will contact the developper.